# Passing information from ancestors in parse tree

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, antlr4

What are the "acceptable" ways of passing information from ancestor to a child node.

For example, if I have an assignment expression that I want to tell each side of the assignment on which side it's (tell the expression on the lhs that it's on lhs and expression on rhs that it's on rhs).

I had the idea to pass the info down using another [ParseTreeProperty](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeProperty.html) different than the one I use to pass information up. Or use the same one for passing information up and down altogether.

Answer (score 0):

LHS_EXP: ~('=')+ ;
EQ: '=' -> mode(RHS_MODE);

mode RHS_MODE;
RHS_EXP: ~(';')+ ;

This way you'll have 3 tokens: LHS_EXP EQ RHS_EXP